# Javascript : Difference between Function and Function. Prototype

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, prototype-chain

If we create a function like:

```
function Rabbit() {}
```

We see that it inherits from the same object that `Function` inherits from i.e.

```
Rabbit.__proto__ === Function.__proto__
```

What is this higher object? If we try to log it it looks like : `ƒ () { [native code] }`. Shouldn't `Rabbit` be inheriting from `Function` object because it's a function? Can somebody explain where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is this higher object?

It's the object referenced by `Function.prototype`, which [is also a function](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-function-prototype-object). It's where functions get their properties and methods from (`call`, `apply`, `bind`, `name`, and `length`).

*That* object's prototype is [the object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-object-prototype-object) referenced by `Object.prototype`, which is responsible for basic object properties and methods such as `hasOwnProperty` and `toString` and, since you used it in your example, `__proto__` (which is a web-only feature for backward compatibility; don't use it, use `Object.getPrototypeOf` instead).

> Shouldn't `Rabbit` be inheriting from `Function` object because it's a function?

No, that's what `Function.prototype` is for.

Let's put `Function`, specifically, aside for a moment. Suppose you have:

```
function Thingy() {
}
```

and

```
let t = new Thingy();
```

`Object.getPrototypeof(t) === Thingy.prototype` will be true, because when you use `new Thingy`, the resulting object gets the object that `Thingy.prototype` points to as its prototype. This is how constructor functions and prototypes work in JavaScript.

`Function` is a constructor that creates functions. So the equivalent would be:

```
let Rabbit = new Function();
```

`Object.getPrototypeOf(Rabbit) === Function.prototype` is true. It's also true for functions that, like your `Rabbit`, aren't created via `new Function`.

Comment: But why keep `Function` and `Function.prototype` separately? Couldn't this be done using one object?

Comment: What do you mean by the same object? Function is a constructor and the prototype is what will be a `__proto__` of a future instance.

Comment: @VSX - `Function` is a constructor function: When you call it via `new Function`, it creates a new function. Like all constructor functions when you use `new X`, the prototype of the new object is taken from `X.prototype`, so that's why `Function` has a `prototype` property with the various features functions typically have on it. `Function` (the function) supplies the initialization of the new object (a function), `Function.prototype` provides the prototype for the object (which, again, is just like other constructor functions).

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't Rabbit be inheriting from Function object because it's a function?

No, because it is a regular function. Every function you create this way is actually a `Function` object instance. See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

In order to make a `Function` be a prototype of your object you need to explicitly specify it as a prototype of your object and create an instance using `new` keyword.

Comment: So creating a function like `function Rabbit() {}` basically does `Rabbit = new Function()` for us?

Comment: Yes. But don't call a constructor directly (not a good manner in most of the cases).

Comment: _But don't call a constructor directly._
You mean only for the native constructors right?

Comment: @VSX - There are several native constructors you may well want to call: `Date`, `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, `WeakSet`, `Int32Array` and related, `Promise`, `Proxy`... But several (`RegExp`, `Object`, `Array`, and `Function`) are better avoided (barring a really good reason) in favor of using the literal syntax provided for those types of objects.